# Accessing my Ingress and its logs on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

So we have a API running Kubernetes and for some reason when I try to call it I get a 503 Temporary unavailable error. Now when I check the server logs they are empty except some Cron-Job that keeps on failing.

Now I'm trying to figure out what's causing this 503 error but since the calls don't even seem to get the API I want to check the Ingress.

Now when I run the command:

*kubectl get ingress*

The name of the Ingress comes up as:

*dett-server-bss-ingress*

However when I run commands to describe the Ingress or access it it says its not there as if its on another server.
Could this be possible and if so how do I find/access it?

Comment: Could you provide some more details? Is this a bare metal or cloud deployment (which provider)? What k8s version are you using?

Comment: Its located on another pod which i have not got access rights to so im kinda stuck.